# Proving that a $W^{1,2}$ type space is Hilbert

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Split the $N-$dimensional Euclidian space as $\mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^{N_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{N_2}$. A vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ will be denoted by $z = (x,y)$. Let $\alpha > 0$ and consider the space
$$
S^{1,2}(\Omega) = \left\{u \in L^2(\Omega) : u_{x_i} \in  L^2(\Omega), |x|^{\alpha}u_{y_j}\in L^2(\Omega), i=1,...,N_1, j=1,...,N_2 \right\}.
$$
This space is endowed with the inner product
$$
(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} [\nabla_x u(z) \cdot \nabla_x v(z) + |x|^{2\alpha} \nabla_y u(z) \cdot \nabla_y v(z)] + \int_{\Omega} uv.
$$
The respective norm is
$$
||u||^2 = \int_{\Omega} |\nabla_x u(z)|^2 + |x|^{2\alpha}|\nabla_y u(z)|^2  + \int_{\Omega} u^2.
$$
This space is related to the Grushin operator. Notice when $\alpha = 0$, $S^{1,2}(\Omega) = W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

In the paper "Compact Embedding of a Degenerate Sobolev Space and Existence of Entire Solutions to a Semilinear Equation for a Grushin-type Operator" is said the $S^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space. I'm trying to prove it, but I got stuck. Any sugestion is welcome.

Comment: Use a Cauchy Sequence with the norm that you defined, and then try to use the completeness of $L_2(\Omega)$
to obtain candidates to be an element in $S^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Comment: I have tried this, but I failed. I had to impose some restrictions on $\alpha$, which seems to be wrong.